# Is there a better way to download a YouTube video in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have a background process kicking off in my Node.js application and I am trying to remove some of the complexity.

Backend receives a YouTube ID from the frontend and kicks off a process to download the video.

Process starts:

```
@Process("download-file-job")
private async handleJob(job: Job) {
  const { data = {} as TranscriptDataInterface } = job;

  const { file, response } = await this.youtubService.downloadYoutubeFile(
    data.sourceId,
    data.id,
  );

  response.end(async () => {
    await this.transcriptProducer.queueJob({
      transcript: data.transcript,
      file: file,
    });
  });
}
```

Download function:

```
public async downloadYoutubeFile(sourcId: string, id: string) {
  const file = `${id}..audio.mp4`;
  const stream = fs.createWriteStream(file);

  const response = ytdl(`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${sourcId}`, {
    quality: 18,
  }).pipe(stream);

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    response.on("finish", resolve);
    response.on("error", reject);
  });

  return {
    file: file,
    response: response,
  };
}
```

The download function is using `ytdl` library and as you can see I am using `createWriteStream`. When the response is returned I take the file and instantly pass it into a second process that calls an AI service to process the file.

The reason I don't like this is because `createWriteStream` writes the file to the file system and I have to clean it up afterwards upon success or error. Is there a way to do this by which I can simply pass the data into the next process without writing the file to the system?